# MySQL : select 3 column names with greatest values from a row

Tags: php, mysql, filter, multiple-columns

I am quite new to MySQL and have following problem:

I need to select 3 column names with the greatest values, whereas my "countries" table is structured like this:

```
countryCode   tag1   tag2   tag3   tag4   tag5   tag6   tag7   tag8

     GB        2      4      4       8      9      1      1     0 
     .
     .
     .
```

So the query should return tag5, tag4, tag3 in this case.
I messed with select max and union, but did not succeed yet.

Any help is appreciated :)

**Further explanation**

```
countryCode backpack beach culture forest mountains scuba trailer
   AD          0       5      85     1       5        6      7  
   AE          7       2      15     1       9        6      7 
   .
   .
   .
```

I am querying from PHP, taking the countryCode as Post. I need to get the result  of the columns with the hightest 3 numbers. For this example; if I query AD, it should return culture, trailer, scuba

Comment: What's the expected output? Just add it to the question.

Comment: I believe you overlooked it, it should return tag5, tag4, tag3 for this case

Comment: only you need to return the column_name right?

Comment: Yes thats true, it is enough if I just get the column names, preferably in some order, asc or desc :)

Comment: See normalization. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, so I added to it a little - supposed I have this input:

```
countryCode   tag1   tag2   tag3   tag4   tag5   tag6   tag7   tag8

     GB        2      4      5       8      9      1      1     0 
     FR        9      4      4       8      9      1      7     0 
     .
     .
```

Then you want the output to be:
    countryCode   number1        number2   number3

```
     GB        tag5           tag4      tag3       
     FR        tag1, tag5     tag4      tag7
```

?

If you expect the above result, max will not help you and the format of your data is not helping. You could possibly do something like the below, which is all sorts of bad...

```
select countryCode, tagName, value from 
(select a.countryCode, 'tag1'  tagName, a.tag1  value from countries a where a.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  b.countryCode, 'tag2'  tagName, b.tag2  value from countries b where b.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  c.countryCode, 'tag3'  tagName, c.tag3  value from countries c where c.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  d.countryCode, 'tag4'  tagName, d.tag4  value from countries d where d.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  e.countryCode, 'tag5'  tagName, e.tag5  value from countries e where e.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  f.countryCode, 'tag6'  tagName, f.tag6  value from countries f where f.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  g.countryCode, 'tag7'  tagName, g.tag7  value from countries g where g.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  h.countryCode, 'tag8'  tagName, h.tag8  value from countries h where h.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  i.countryCode, 'tag9'  tagName, i.tag9  value from countries i where i.countryCode = 'GB' UNION
select  j.countryCode, 'tag10' tagName, j.tag10 value from countries j where j.countryCode = 'GB' ) 
as results
order by value desc
limit 3;
```

EDIT: Just a sample of the data and table structure I've got. I'm running this in MySQL 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, just in case this is a version difference. So if you adjust my sample query above, that should work.

```
mysql> desc countries;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| countryCode | varchar(2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag1        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag2        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag3        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag4        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag5        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag6        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag7        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag8        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag9        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag10       | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from countries;
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| countryCode | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 | tag4 | tag5 | tag6 | tag7 | tag8 | tag9 | tag10 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| GB          |    5 |    1 |    2 |    5 |    7 |    8 |    9 |    3 |   15 |    22 |
| FR          |    5 |   14 |    2 |    5 |    7 |    8 |    9 |    3 |   15 |    22 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ideally though, if you are getting this data somewhere else, it maybe easier and more recommended to use the other table, as the query I've sent you will be slow.

The ideal scenario is that you have a table Country Code and Tag that you could use an aggregate function directly on it.

Comment: I can not seem to to run this query, it returns syntax error if I do like this: select countryCode, tagName, value from 
(select a.countryCode, 'beach'  tagName, a.beach  value from countries a where a.countryCode = 'AD' UNION
select  b.countryCode, 'backpack'  tagName, b.backpack  value from countries b where b.countryCode = 'AD' UNION
select  c.countryCode, 'scuba'  tagName, c.scuba  value from countries c where c.countryCode = 'AD' UNION ) 
as results
order by value desc
limit 1;

Comment: I've added a data sample and my table structure - so if you have something similar, that query should work. I'd say that if you need this a a once in a blue moon script and have low performance requirements, than yes you can use that query - or else, I'd say you need to find this data in a different format, like this for instance 
    country_code | varchar(2) 
    tag_name     | varchar(128)
    tag_count   | int(11)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Already convinced to design it properly :) I will create an additional table containing country codes, tags and values. Cant upvote since I dont have enough reputation point.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed you had an extra UNION on your query in the comment above: 
select countryCode, tagName, value from (select a.countryCode, 'beach' tagName, a.beach value from countries a where a.countryCode = 'AD' UNION select b.countryCode, 'backpack' tagName, b.backpack value from countries b where b.countryCode = 'AD' UNION select c.countryCode, 'scuba' tagName, c.scuba value from countries c where c.countryCode = 'AD') as results order by value desc limit 1;